# Java function with list of classes implementing interface as argument

Tags: java, generics

I have a list of classes which implement a certain interface:

```
List<Class<? extends DatabaseField>> models = new ArrayList<Class<? extends DatabaseField>>();
```

I would like to pass this list to a function which iterates over that list, and uses one or two interface functions.

What would the function signature look like?

I have tried things such as:

```
public static void <List<Class<T implements DatabaseField>> myMethod(List<Class<T>> myList)
```

And am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What's wrong with `public static void myMethod(List<Class<? extends DatabaseField>> myList)`? Though, it's unclear how you actually intend to use this list in the first place. Maybe you should include an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Given the list of classes, I want to generically instantiate one of each and use interface methods.

Answer (score 0):

try this, as it should work.

```
public static <T extends DatabaseField> void myMethod(List<T> myList) {

}
```

Comment: It does compile provided I add `Class<T implements DatabaseField>` in the argument list - thank you - but won't type match with the invocation at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature should be:

```
public static void myMethod(List<Class<? extends DatabaseField>> myList)
```

You can then iterate over `myList` and operate on the class objects as you desire:

```
for(Class<? extends DatabaseField> clazz : myList) {
    DatabaseField obj = clazz.newInstance();
    obj.databaseFieldMethod();
}
```